# Preview Content-Type video/mp4 as video not working on Insomnia

Tags: insomnia

I got this trouble.! When I make a request to the API to see a video, the preview of the results is like the image.
This image is Header from result API

```
NAME    VALUE
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length  886752
Content-Type    video/mp4
Date    Tue, 19 Mar 2024 05:46:20 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Vary    Origin
Vary    Origin
Vary    Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary    Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Ratelimit-Limit   -1
X-Ratelimit-Remaining   0
X-Ratelimit-Reset   0
X-Xss-Protection    1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Set-Cookie  TS01f09d47=011a292347b28d4d0e2a883d4128f7aef844a586f53d69dd976a2b9d42ddd48904d363590a4d7888a02fc7e267e0e9712e659ea909;
```

[Headers Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hHOD.png)
And this is Preview from result API
[Preview Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoI4g.png)